# Word Processor for Mac with the clean HTML output?

Tags: html, word-processor

I need spell checking and only basic formatting (like the stack overflow editor). It would also be nice if you could switch to HTML editing and also paste formatted text into it and it will convert to basic HTML (like TinyMCE does).

I have tried MS Office, LibreOffice and TextEdit but they both produce very dirty results e.g. lots of `spans` containing a class and just have a space as the content.

Is there a free and basic/lightweight desktop (offline) word processor for OS X 10.7 that produces clean HTML output? I am looking to write articles and not web sties.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/) seems to be exactly what I need. It is a little bit sluggish but seems to work quite well. It has spell checking and handles copy and pasting from Word into it.

It is based on the Firefox rendering engine, free and works on Windows, OS X and Linux.

Answer (score -1):

I have not extensively used either but both of these should do the job:

- [Mou](http://mouapp.com/)
- [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) (not Free)